# Получение динамической переменной из Twig в PHP

Tags: php, twig, dynamic

Есть шаблон

```
<fieldset>
                            {% if clientFriend %} {% set cfInfo = clientFriend.info() %} {% endif %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="friendName" class="hidden"></label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ФИО"
                                       name="friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][name]"
                                        {% if cfInfo.friend_name %} value="{{ cfInfo.friend_name }}" {% endif %}>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="phoneFriend" class="hidden"></label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон"
                                       name="friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][phone]"
                                {% if cfInfo.phone_friend %} value="{{ cfInfo.phone_friend }}" {% endif %}>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-outline-blue-sm">
                                    Добавить 
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </fieldset>
```

и из него нужно получить в мой класс добавления переменную  name="friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][name]" через $_POST

но я не могу его получить получая ошибку

Notice: Undefined index: friend[{{ cfInfo.id }}][name]

есть идеи?

Comment: посмотрите для начала, что у вас в `$_POST`и попробуйте как-то связать это со значением в `cfInfo.id`

Comment: вот что из $_POST приходит ко мне
(+ еще они почему-то не в одном массиве)

Array
(
    [friend] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Доверенное Лицо Ивана
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [phone] => +7-437-437-2472
                )

        )

)